# Umbraco vs Sitefinity

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco, sitefinity

I am getting a large website developed. The develop has asked me which do I prefer either sitefinity or umbraco. The site will be similar to wikipedia where users can come and edit pages without having to login. I would like to ask your opionions on these two csm systems and which one would you recommend for content website with a community feel and wiki features. Thanks

Comment: HI Luke, what did you go with? I'm looking at both Site Infinity and Umbraco as well and wondering what you chose and what your experience was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a non-commercial (charity?) site, you may be able to obtain the community version of Sitefinity for free if you display their logo in the footer. Sitefinity has a lot to offer, including an ORM.

Umbraco on the other hand has, for me personally, an unhealthy reliance on XSLT to customize the content. That was the main reason I didn't go with it.

I would go for Sitefinity or N2 for this.

Comment: You don't have to use any XSLT in Umbraco if you don't want to, though it is very handy as a way to seperate out the presentation of your site.

Comment: @Sebastian, that's interesting; I must check it out again. The ASPNET site is Umbraco I believe? Can we use SQL Server with it? +1 :-)

Comment: Yes, the asp.net site uses it and wired.co.uk as well (and other big sites). Instead of XSLT you could always use .net user controls. SQL Server would be the best choice, Umbraco also works with MySQL and recently SQL Server CE.

Comment: They're charging 3,000 euros for support...

Comment: As far as I am aware, Sitefinity Community Edition has no restrictions on being commercial.

Comment: BTW, the Sitefinity ORM you mention is a seperate (commercial) Telerik product. Sitefinity may just have support for it.

Comment: @dotnetdev, does that mean we pay extra for the ORM?

Comment: Umbraco doesn't require any purchase or license to run it.  The support is an option if you want support from Umbraco the company.  Also, Umbraco supports the Iron* languages and Linq so really you can use nearly any language you are comfortable with.

Comment: That said, I've used Sitefinity as well and its a good cheaper option on some projects.  I just don't like how it uses ASP.NET controls for everything.

Comment: The Sitefinity Community Edition appears to have been discontinued: http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet/forums/sitefinity-3-x/set-up-installation/future-of-sitefinity-community-edition.aspx

Comment: I use Umbraco and have used Sitefinity v4&5. I leave Sitefinity off of my resume because I often find the features half baked and development is a bear. For instance, if you try to get an item that has been deleted through the API it throws a null pointer exception rather than returning null or at least a ItemNotFound exception. Another instance is that you can add fields to a page but it wont save the data you put in those fields. I am talking primarily from experience on v5. I loath that CMS.

Comment: Everyone in our company hates it from our IT department, to our design department, to our programming department, to the client who consistently has to get us to manage content because the CMS has crazy caching issues and is a hog on the cpu/ram.

Answer (score 8):

I disagree with @IrishChieftain's answer and would most certainly go with **Umbraco**!

I've built a number of websites in Umbraco (and have got my certification) and I have to say I absolutely love it!

XSLT is very easy to learn unless you come across some really complex functionality. But even then, you can resort to ASP.NET if you don't want to learn XSLT.

Comment: Hi Marko, I work every day with a huge ASPNET site that uses XML/XSLT. But, given a choice I would opt for CSS to control my display and apply it to user controls if possible :-)

Comment: Umbraco doesn't change your ability to use CSS.  XSLT merely outputs HTML markup and you have complete control over that markup.  This is why we like Umbraco, it doesn't have a set of ASP.NET Controls to do everything and the markup stays very clean.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what others have suggested, I find the use of XSLT in Umbraco advantageous on numerous levels.  In particular the time it takes to make changes and see their results is very quick.  Just create transform and put a macro in your page and you can see the results.  You get access to all the site data as necessary directly in the transform.  Also, the fact that you are just working in HTML within the XSL transform means that it would be easy for a non .NET web developer to make changes too.  I've found that although this is a .NET based CMS there is little reason to perform anything in code so you only really have to have open the CMS and your favourite text editor (I'd suggest using a text editor and accessing static files this way (through FTP or whatever if you're not logged in to the machine the CMS is on) rather than through the CMS interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a CMS for a large website and with wiki features, look at Kentico CMS. It was designed for large number of documents and it's the most advanced .NET CMS I have seen.

It has a built-in user-contribution module that allows public users to create new content items from the live site and you can control who can do that (all/authenticated/selected roles) and what type of content items (news/pages/knowledge base articles) they can create. Kentico has a free version, but for this type of functionality, you would need a paid license. Still, if it meets your needs for user contributed content, it may pay for itself very quickly since AFAIK no other .NET CMS has this built-in.

Comment: I haven't used Umbraco or Sitefinity... yet, but I have been impressed by Kentico.  I have used Ektron CMS400.net and DotNetNuke, and wouldn't recommend them to my worst enemy... if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco was possibly the worst CMS a few years back when it was in version 2. Things have changed though and, for me, it jumped to the top of the list when it hit version 4. I find Umbraco to be the easiest CMS to manage and develop in. The XSLT is probably the hardest thing to get used to here, but like others mentioned it isn't a show stopper because you can still do everything using Umbraco data access layer. The one thing i absolutely love about it is how easy it is for the end user. The UI is very intuitive and easy to grasp. The only downside i see with Umbraco is bugs and there are a whole lot of them even in version 4 releases. Most of them are UI bugs. However, some do affect advanced features such as packages. I would still go with Umbraco if i had to pick a choose a CMS for a project of any size.